# Google earth Borders on Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Google earth comes with a variety of borders, for example:
International Borders
1st Level Admin Borders
2nd Level Admin Regions

I was wondering if it is possible to render these borders on Google maps, in the same way we can render kml files.

Does anyone know where this information is stored?  Is it at Google's end, or having installed Google earth, is it at my end?  Are they just KML files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible for you to access the underlying geometry that is used to represent these borders in Google Earth.  Nor is it possible to use them separately in Google Maps as KML.

Your best bet would be to find a My Maps layer (if you can find one).

Answer (score 2):

[NaturalEarth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/) has several levels of administrative borders, so does  OpenStreetMap (for certain parts of the world). You could then convert shapefiles or OSM files into KML using various tools.

Answer (score 0):

GADM has a fairly decent set of country and administrative district borders: (http://gadm.org/), but sadly they are a bit out of date and take a bit of tweaking if you want to reflect the curr